# playing multiple videos simultaneously on Android with HTML5

Tags: android, html5-video

Has anyone tried playing multiple videos simultaneously in Android using HTML5 ? This is well documented in Apple saying iOS does not support multiple videos in HTML5. Does anyone know if there are similar restrictions on Android with HTML5 ?

Answer (score -1):

I haven't really tried playing multiple videos but i have tried in playing one youtube video and it works fine.

You can try is you can make multiple webviews in a single screen and inflate each of those webviews with a youtube/normal video and it would work just fine.